# Codeship : review env deletion on branch merged

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, codeship

Looking in the documentation i can't find any easy way to remove the environment provisionned on the deploy step when the given branch is merged on master or deleted.

Any hint on if this is even possible with Codeship ?

Answer (score 1):

is this a CodeShip Basic or Pro project? It may be helpful to have you reach out to us at [helpdesk.codeship.com](https://helpdesk.codeship.com) so we can get a clearer idea of whats going on. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Basic, but upgrade to pro can be considered if this is the way to go.